# Summary Statistics for sparse, imbalanced, observational data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, marginal-model

I am trying to find a good summary statistic (next step is going to be inference) for my problem. I have observational data that is images for patients (factor1) with different conditions (factor2) that is coming from 3 locations (factor3). The images was measuring multiple skin marker areas.

Now the thing is not all patients are having the same number of images across the 3 locations. So, I am wondering how to normalize that?

My thoughts were to get the median of area per each combination of the 3 factors, but I think I am losing a lot of data this way. Also, this will introduce more imbalance for further inferential statistics. I have seen some people using **marginal means** in a similar scenario but I found some resources that mentioned it is no good for observational data with no alternatives specified.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.